# Nao consigo usa o strcmp em C

Tags: c, if, else

Preciso fazer mostrar a ficha de um aluno usando a matricula, como faço?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {

  struct ficha {
    char matricula[9], inf[9];
    char nome[50];
    char curso[20];
    char periodo[10];
  };
  struct ficha alunos[2];

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("\nInforme a matricula do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].matricula);

    printf("\nInforme o nome do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].nome);

    printf("\nInforme o curso do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].curso);

    printf("\nInforme o periodo do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].periodo);
  }

  printf("\n\nDigite uma das matriculas para informacoes de um aluno:");
  scanf("%s", & alunos[i].inf);

  if (strcmp(alunos[i].matricula, alunos[i].inf) == 0) {
    printf("\n\n---------------------------Informacoes---------------------------\n\n");

    printf("\nMatricula: %s \n", alunos[i].matricula);
    printf("\nNome: %s \n", alunos[i].nome);
    printf("\nCurso: %s \n", alunos[i].curso);
    printf("\nPeriodo: %s \n", alunos[i].periodo);

  } else
    printf("Aluno nao encontrado");
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", & alunos[i].inf);` repare no seu código que esta linha está fora do `for`, ou seja, vai usar o último valor que tiver na variável "i". essa propriedade "inf" nem precisaria estar na `struct` se vai ler só uma vez, poderia ser uma variável comum. E deveria em seguida fazer um `for` para procurar esse valor e ver se foi digitado

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Conforme coloquei no comentário, está usando `scanf("%s", & alunos[i].inf);` fora do `for`, ou seja, vai ler um valor em "i" com o último valor do `for` e essa comparação não vai funcionar.

O valor procurado pode ser uma variável separada, que não precisa estar na `struct` já que não vai ler dentro do `for`, assim por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {

  struct ficha {
    char matricula[9];
    char nome[50];
    char curso[20];
    char periodo[10];
  };
  
  struct ficha alunos[2];
  
  char pesquisa[9];
  bool achou = false;

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("\nInforme a matricula do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].matricula);

    printf("\nInforme o nome do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].nome);

    printf("\nInforme o curso do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].curso);

    printf("\nInforme o periodo do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", & alunos[i].periodo);
  }

  printf("\n\nDigite uma das matriculas para informacoes de um aluno:");
  scanf("%s", & pesquisa);

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (strcmp(alunos[i].matricula, pesquisa) == 0) {
        printf("\n\n---------------------------Informacoes---------------------------\n\n");

        printf("\nMatricula: %s \n", alunos[i].matricula);
        printf("\nNome: %s \n", alunos[i].nome);
        printf("\nCurso: %s \n", alunos[i].curso);
        printf("\nPeriodo: %s \n", alunos[i].periodo);
        achou = true;
    }
  }
  
  if (achou == false) {
       printf("\nAluno nao encontrado");
  }

  system("pause");
}
```

Note que, após ler o valor, o `strcmp` está dentro de um `for` para comparar com cada valor que foi digitado, até achar. Para o caso de não achar, criei a variável "achou" que vai ter o valor inicial "false" e vai mudar para "true" caso encontre.

Ao final tem o condicional `if (achou == false)` para exibir a mensagem caso não tenha encontrado, que também poderia ser `if (!achou)`

Comment: Eu nunca tinha usado esse bool, mas acho que entendi como funcionou o código, obrigado!

Comment: podeira ser tbm `int` e zero ser o "false" e um o "true" :)